# Matplotlib bug: Data is shown above spine with twinx()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot two data sets that differ by some orders of magnitude. After some research (it was literally one google search away) I found out about the `twinx()` function.

However, I've run into some trouble when using it. I'm producing publication-grade figures with this tool, and there is something that is bugging me.

System: matplotlib v1.3.1, python v2.7.4 on Ubuntu

Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator


time = np.arange(0, 365, 1)
y1 = np.random.rand(len(time)) * np.exp(-0.03 * time)
y2 = 0.001 * np.random.rand(len(time)) * np.exp(-0.02 * time)

for i in range(30):
    y2[-i] = 0

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6), dpi=300)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0, right=0.9, top=0.94, left=0.12, bottom=0.07)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

for tl in ax1.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('r')
for tl in ax2.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('b')

for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(
        nbins=5,
        steps=[1,2,3,4,5,10],
        integer=False,
        symmetric=False,
        prune=None))
    ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(4))

ax2.plot(time, y1, 'b-')
ax1.plot(time, y2, 'r-')
ax1.set_ylabel(r"y value", labelpad=15)
ax1.set_xlabel(r"x value")
ax1.set_xlim(0,365)
ax1.set_xticks(range(0,370,30))
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(3))

fig.savefig("Errorplot.png", dpi=60)
```

Now, when looking at this low resolution output, I see nothing weird:
[image: Error plot]

However, when zooming in on a high-resolution (say, `dpi=300`) version, I see the following:
[image: Zoomed section of the error plot]

It is obvious that the lines in the second axes are drawn over the spine of the first.

How do I alleviate this problem? Is there a way to redraw the spines of an axes instance?

### What I've tried

- Changing the order of the `plot()` calls
- Setting the `zorder` kwarg to -1, -10. Even when the ax2 zorder was smaller than the ax1, I had this behaviour.
- In combination with the above: `ax2.spines['bottom'].set_zorder(10)`

Comment: I can't replicate your error. When I run your code and look at the .png (I've boosted the dpi up to 1200 so it's really fine pixels) I find that all spines are above the data points.

Comment: I am still using `v 1.2.1`. Possibly an update will solve this for me.

Comment: Ah yeah I am on 1.3.1. See if an update fixes it, and if not let us know.

Comment: Well, I just did the update to `1.3.1` (even checked the matplotlib.__version__ variable) and still have the same problem...

Comment: I'm sorry I actually misunderstood your problem. I've found a fix for it now and will post the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

It does not seem this post gets many views but I found it helpful and would like to add another way to change the `zorder` on the off chance it will help someone else.  This [post](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Control-twinx-series-zorder-ax2-series-behind-ax1-series-or-place-ax2-on-left-ax1-on-right-td12994.html) more closely matched what I wanted to do but the important thing is changing the `zorder`, which @Ffisegydd's outlined.  Another way to do this is using the following:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.set_zorder(ax2.get_zorder()+1) # put ax1 in front of ax2 
ax1.patch.set_visible(False) # hide the 'canvas' 

ax1.plot(data1[:,0], data1[:,0])  # plot whatever data you want
ax2.plot(data2[:,0], data2[:,0])  # plot commands can precede the set_zorder command
```

I realize this does not directly solve the asked question but hopefully it can help someone who, like me, finds this post searching for a solution to a closely related issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`zorder` kwarg](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_zorder) in matplotlib to change the order that objects are drawn, see an example code [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html)

Below I have added two examples (I have cut out the majority of your code to save space). In one example I set the `zorder` to a larger value, meaning that it will be drawn last (and hence on top). In the other example I set `zorder` to -1 meaning that it will be drawn first (and hence below).

```
ax2.plot(time, y1, 'b-', zorder=5)
ax1.plot(time, y2, 'r-', zorder=5)
```

[image: Example plot]

```
ax2.plot(time, y1, 'b-', zorder=-1)
ax1.plot(time, y2, 'r-', zorder=-1)
```

[image: Example plot 2]

Comment: Even when setting the `zorder` kwarg to -1 as you suggest, I still get half of the spine overwritten by the blue line...

Comment: Can you upload an example to imgur showing what you mean and post it in a comment? Because for me using `zorder=-1` it seems to look perfectly fine.

Comment: Well if I set the zorder to - 1 (for both plots mind you) then I get what is shown above, which clearly shows the spine above both plots.

Comment: Even when I set the zorder to something lower in ax2 than ax1, it gets drawn above the other line. Something wonky is going on here...

Comment: Also I notice that in your second image, the blue data is drawn above the tick marks and the red data below. If both have `zorder=-1`, how can that happen?